# Why JavaScript ignores the HTML <br/> label when trying to concatenate it with the result of the operator OR?

Tags: javascript, html, logic, operators

Sorry for the question, I wasn't sure how to ask it. Basically I'm practicing JavaScript using logic operators. I have a really simple HTML code:

`<body> <script src="logic_operators.js"></script> </body>`

The file "logic_operators.js" has the next lines of code:

```
let value1 = true;
let value2 = false;

document.write(value1 && value2 + '<br/>');
document.write(value1 || value2 + '<br/>');
document.write(!value1 + '<br/>');
document.write(!value2 + '<br/>');
```

Basically, each `document.write()` sentence writes the result of each logic operant with a new line.

It works for each sentence except for the OR ( || ) one, it doesn't print the new line. I get the next result:

```
false
truefalse
true
```

I need to enclose the OR operation using parenthesis for the sentence to work:

`document.write((value1 || value2) + '<br/>');`

Why is that? I'm new to JavaScript and can't really figure this out.

Comment: b/c otherwise it's read as `docwrite value1 === true or (value2===true + <br>)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`+` has higher [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) than `||`. Specifically, + has 14 and || has 6. So, the `+` operation is done first, when there aren't parentheses grouping the three operators.

```
document.write(value1 || value2 + '<br/>');
```

is

```
document.write(value1 || (value2 + '<br/>')
```

resulting in

```
document.write(true || (false + '<br/>')
```

```
document.write(true)
```

The `&&` also has lower precedence than `+`. `&&` evaluates to the last operand if the first is truthy. So

```
document.write(value1 && value2 + '<br/>');
```

```
document.write(true && false + '<br/>');
```

```
document.write(true && (false + '<br/>'));
```

```
document.write(false + '<br/>');
```

So it *happens* to produce the newline like you want for these particular values of `value1` and `value2`.

While you can avoid this problem by using parentheses, or by using [writeln](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/writeln) instead, it would be [much, much better to avoid `document.write` completely.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)

Comment: I guess same goes for &&?

Comment: @Kinglish Was about to ask the same. It's weird because it doesn't seem to work with && the same way, It actually applies the new line, even thought it also has a lower operator precedence.

Comment: @DamianGDO See the middle part of the answer

Comment: I'm so dumb, I literally didn't see that somehow the first time, must have blinked out.